# Making Netty synchronous?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty

Hello I am a student just starting to learn Netty framework.
I am building a HTTP server with Netty.

I am using Netty 4.0.7. My server is based on the Netty 4.0.6 example HttpUploadServer.

Please bear with me if I'm wrong... I am confused about the whole concept of asynchronous networking.

Let me give you an example(Lifecycle of my server)

1. The client sends a multipart POST request.
2. The server reads the request chunck by chunck(in channelRead0 method)
3. Then the server does some work with the chuncked data and sends a response. However the work requires uses of global variable.(For example, a String with header content or some public method)

So here's my question.

How can I put a lock(make synchronous) on some methods and variables so that they don't conflit with each other (while handling requests that does not use those global variables asynchronously)?

Or am I just getting the concept of asynchronous server wrong?

Comment: You can put synchronized block in the part of your code that you want to protect,instead of making the whole method as synchronized.

Comment: It seems like the handler makes sure that this does not happen. I've ran a test with multiple connections using the same global variable and there are no conflicts. I'm not sure if I did this right, can someone approve this?

Comment: Netty's Thread-Model makes sure that all its events are handled by only one Thread per Channel. So you should be fine.